# Excel fails to hide more than 53 rows

Tags: excel, vba

This is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
        If Range("A2").Value = "Select" Then
            ActiveSheet.Rows("5:61").Select
            Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

For some reason, if the range is higher than "5:58", I get a Run-time error '1004'.

Comment: Do you have any merged cells in rows after row 58?

Answer (score 1):

This code is working in Excel 2013, unfortunately I have no other versions. As I am no fan of references to active workbooks and active sheets and the use of selection, can you can also use

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
        If Range("A2").Value = "Select" Then
            Target.Parent.Rows("5:61").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Target.Parent refers to the sheet containing the range.

Comment: Checked the same in 2010 - works too. Had a similar problem where an hide didn't work after a selection - maybe without the selection the problem is already solved...

Comment: I tried it, same error. I also tried it on a blank document and it worked. It might have something to do with content.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Excel are you using? I tried your code on Excel 2007 and it works. I removed the selection line and tried it this way, this also works.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
        If Range("A2").Value = "Select" Then
            ActiveSheet.Rows("5:61").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I am using Excel 2010

Comment: I tried merging cells between rows 5 to 61 thinking that could be a reason for failure but no, it works ok as well. What sort of data you have between these rows?

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct and working.

The problem was caused by the fact that I had to many hidden rows/columns. Excel only allows you to hide a limited amount.

Answer (score 1):

simple work-around for you :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
    If Range("A2").Value = "Select" Then
        Dim Rg as Range
        For each Rg in Target.Parent.Rows("5:61") 'not sure if you need to add a .rows here, just try
            Rg.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        next Rg
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

this way it hides only one row at a time.